# How can i fix " Class 'App\Service' not found "

Tags: php, laravel-5, relationship, cpanel

in local host i haven't this problem but in linux host in CPannel i receive this error

Class 'App\Service' not found

it's just an example i have same problem in some models..

my relations doesnt work properly in original host but in local host i haven't got any problem

my models:

```
<?php


namespace App;

use App\Category;

use App\Project;

use App\Service;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Category extends Model

{

    protected $fillable = [

        'title', 'parent_id','title_en',
    ];


    public function category(){
        return  $this->hasMany(Category::class,'parent_id');
    }

    public function parent(){
        return $this->category('parent');
    }

    public function project(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(project::class);
    }

    public function service(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(service::class);
    }
}
```

my controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Service;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class ServiceController extends Controller
{

    public function landpage(){

        $services=Service::with('cat')->get();


        return view('services.index',compact('services'));
    }

    public function detail($id){

        $services=service::with('cat')->findOrFail($id);

        return view('service_detail.index',compact('services'));

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run/configured an autoload dump?

Comment: Try `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` or using `artisan clear-compiled` on server side

Comment: If your localhost is a Windows system, double-check that the case of your files and class names matches. Windows is a case-insensitive filesystem, so it would be fine loading the `Service` class from either `service.php` or `Service.php`. But Linux is case-sensitive, so it would have to be `Service.php`.

Comment: Seems like the [same question you asked a few hours before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401830/how-can-fix-this-error-class-app-category-not-found).  I've never seen you answer a comment, nor accept an answer, so no idea if you were able to resolve this from the previous question or not, but likely this should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

ok as i found .. the models are sensitive to capital words..

i changed all of the models to capital words..

App/service => App/Service

and it worked